# Does ZeroClipboard only work under Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, zeroclipboard

I found an [example](http://blog.aajit.com/easy-multiple-copy-to-clipboard-by-zeroclipboard/)  and [code](http://blog.aajit.com/demos/MultipleZeroClipboard/copytoclip.zip) how to copy text to clipboard with ZeroClipboard. However, it seems only to work under Firefox and does not work under Chrome/Chromium (39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)). What need to be change to get it to work under Chrome/Chromium as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave does not work on chrome, maybe the version of zeroclipboard is old. You can find the latest version from official [website](http://zeroclipboard.org/). It does work on chrome 39.0 on windows 7.

Comment: I changed to the new version, but now it does not work under any browser. Do I need to change the code?

Comment: I have tried replacing to latest files on that demo. It works fine on chrome too. And the demo on that site also works on chrome. tested. Are you working on local server? It will not work, written on that website. But on web server it works, I have uploaded the same files on my server. It works, just wait for 4-5 sec to load the flash. Check this link on chrome http://debug.bugs3.com/testclipboard/copy2clip.html